# Effective way to manipulate existing python code from file

Tags: python, data-manipulation

I have a (broken) python code which is generated by an external program. Problem is, the generated code is broken (or just exported badly). I'd like to create a script which changes the broken code based on predefined rules.
For example, consider this code:

```
def test_1TestName(self):
    time.sleep(1000)
    assert "a" == "self.vars["value"]"
```

I'd like to fix it by adding changes, for example:

```
@pytest.mark.order(1)
def Test_TestName(self):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("hello")
    assert "a" == self.vars["value"]
```

1. Add a decorator
2. Change the function name.
3. Change sleep time.
4. Add lines.
5. Change comparison.
   etc.

This can be done by going over the file line by line.
I was wondering if there's a better way, more pythonic way, of achieving this, perhaps loading the functions to objects, modifying the object and write it back to file.

Answer (score 0):

I end up using `peekable` from `more_itertools` which allows you to peek into the next line without advancing the cursor.